# Oracle Monitoring RMAN: report need backup

Tags: oracle, rman

Hello Oracle Database Admins!

In the last few months I came across that it would be a good idea to monitor rman backups and check if any file needs backup.

```
RMAN> report need backup;
--> Report ERROR if any records show up.
```

Aditionally I would like to monitor the following command:

```
RMAN> report unrecoverable;
--> Report ERROR if any records show up.
```

I do not want to parse the output of RMAN. *So here is my question:* **Does anyone know a method to monitor these two commands using SQL and/or PL/SQL?**

I know that RMAN just uses SQL and PL/SQL to get the result but an sqltrace just lead me into non-documented pl/sql funtions with encrypted code.

Comment: Does anyone monitor this at all?

Comment: So, did you try calling that undocumented plsql code? The code might be encrypted but the output most likely wouldn't be.

Comment: I was hoping that anyone out threre already did that and could give me a hand. When I will do it, I'll post the outcome here. But right now I have little time. The sql trace was already helpful. Maybe I have to do the trace again with 11g. 12c seems to be much more complicated because of the cdb feature.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Yes, I'll write an "answer" for better formating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Oracle replied to my SR that it is not supported run the SQLs manually. This is not entirely correct but I expected something like that.

B) The second command `report unrecoverable` can be queried with SQL. The result is even more accurate than from RMAN.

```
select file#, unrecoverable_change#, unrecoverable_time from v$datafile;
```

RMAN's `report unrecoveryble` will only report files which contain content which are unrecoveryble *after* the latest backup. This SQL reports unrecoverable things in general. Normally we do not try to make the database *only* recoverable after the latest backup.

C) For both commands I wrote a "screen reader". Here are some code snippets:

```
## Execute RMAN command report need backup
RMANOUT=$(rman target / << EOF 2>&1
report need backup;
exit
EOF
)

## Execute RMAN command report unrecoverable
RMANOUT=$(rman target / << EOF 2>&1
report unrecoverable;
exit
EOF
)

# Filter file list
DATAFILES=$(echo -e "${RMANOUT}" | sed '1,/---/d' | sed '/Recovery Manager complete./d' | sed 's/RMAN>//g' | sed '/^[[:space:]]/d')


## Parse all files
while IFS=$'\n' read -a ROW
do
  # Convert lines into array (separator " ")
  IFS=' ' read -a VAL <<< ${ROW[0]}

  # No files reported
  if [ "${VAL}" == "" ]; then break; fi

  # Do whatever you like! In my case generate XMLdoc
  XMLDOC="${XMLDOC}<ROW><DBID>${DBID}</DBID><INST_ID>${INST_ID}</INST_ID><FILE_ID>${VAL[0]}</FILE_ID><BACKUP_CNT>${VAL[1]}</BACKUP_CNT><FILE_NAME>${VAL[2]}</FILE_NAME></ROW>"
done < <(echo -e "${DATAFILES}")
```